# Inserting vertical space after a particular reference (bibtex)

Tags: spacing, bibtex, bibliographies

I would like to insert some vertical space after a particular reference in the references section with BibTeX, ideally with a sequence of commands like:

```
\cite{ABC-2001} 
\refvspace{1cm} 
\cite{XYZ-2002}
```

The references are imported with `\bibliography{references.bib}`. The order is in the order of citation. The bibliography style is a custom one but let's say it is `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` for definiteness.

> How to do this without modifying the bib-file?

A possible starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@misc{P, author = {P}, year = {2001}}
@misc{Q, author = {Q}, year = {2002}}
@misc{A, author = {A}, year = {2001}}
@misc{B, author = {B}, year = {2002}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    This is a survey on different topics.

    \section*{Topic 1}

    Text \cite{P}. Text \cite{Q}.

    \section*{Topic 2}

    % TODO: Visually separate the two topics in the bibliography here

    Text \cite{A}. Text \cite{B}.

    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A problem might arise: The order of references as they appear in the `References` is not necessarily the order you used the `\cite` command, so this (yet) imaginary `\refvspace` command should know in advance where the full reference is printed in `References`

Comment: You should make a complete example. It matters if you use biblatex or not, and which bibliography style.

Comment: I didn't wrote "include a few details" but "make a complete example". I don't want to spend my time to build a test file from your snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider your input:

```
\cite{ABC-2001} 
\refvspace{1cm} 
\cite{XYZ-2002}
```

We can assign some `\vspace` macro that would tie into the citation for `XYZ-2002`. That is, call `\vspace{1cm}` as soon as it finds `\bibitem{XYZ-2002}` in the bibliography.

The following minimal example achieves this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@misc{P, author = {P}, year = {2001}}
@misc{Q, author = {Q}, year = {2002}}
@misc{A, author = {A}, year = {2001}}
@misc{B, author = {B}, year = {2002}}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\let\@refvspace\relax
\providecommand{\refvspace}[1]{%
  \gdef\@refvspace{#1}% Store \refvspace
}
\let\old@cite\cite% Store \cite in \old@cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{%
  \ifx\@refvspace\relax
    % No \refvspace was used
  \else
    \begingroup
    % Create vspace macro
    \edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\global\noexpand\@namedef{#1@vspace}{\noexpand\vspace{\@refvspace}}}\x
    \global\let\@refvspace\relax
  \fi
  \old@cite{#1}}% Process regular \cite
\let\old@bibitem\bibitem% Store \bibitem in \old@bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{%
  \csname #1@vspace\endcsname% Insert \vspace macro
  \old@bibitem{#1}}% Process regular \bibitem
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is a survey on different topics.

\section*{Topic 1}

Text \cite{P}. \refvspace{\baselineskip}Text \cite{Q}.

\section*{Topic 2}

\refvspace{1cm}

Text \cite{A}. Text \cite{B}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

Caveats:

- The example above is fairly trivial and removes the optional arguments from `\cite` and `\bibitem`. However, that can be restored if needed.
- Content is not written to the `.bib` nor the `.bbl` and therefore would only work if the `\bibliography` occurs *after* all your `\refvspace` macros.

Comment: How does the extra space between [1] and [2] in the output come about?